# How to get the application executable name in WindowsC++/CLI?

Tags: .net, winapi, c++-cli

I need to change the functionality of an application based on the executable name. Nothing huge, just changing strings that are displayed and some internal identifiers. The application is written in a mixture of native and .Net C++-CLI code.

Two ways that I have looked at are to parse the GetCommandLine() function in Win32 and stuffing around with the AppDomain and other things in .Net. However using GetCommandLine won't always work as when run from the debugger the command line is empty. And the .Net AppDomain stuff seems to require a lot of stuffing around.

So what is the nicest/simplest/most efficient way of determining the executable name in C++/CLI? (I'm kind of hoping that I've just missed something simple that is available in .Net.)

Edit: One thing that I should mention is that this is a Windows GUI application using C++/CLI, therefore there's no access to the traditional C style main function, it uses the Windows WinMain() function.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Call [GetModuleFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx) using 0 as a module handle.

**Note:** you *can* also use the `argv[0]` parameter to main or call `GetCommandLine()` if there is no main. However, keep in mind that these methods will not necessarily give you the complete path to the executable file. They will give back the same string of characters that was used to start the program. Calling `GetModuleFileName()`, instead, will always give you a complete path and file name.

Answer (score 16):

Ferruccio's answer is good. Here's some example code:

```
TCHAR exepath[MAX_PATH+1];

if(0 == GetModuleFileName(0, exepath, MAX_PATH+1))
    MessageBox(_T("Error!"));

MessageBox(exepath, _T("My executable name"));
```

Comment: From msdn: `If the function fails, the return value is 0 (zero)` so yeah... you may want to use `==` instead of `!=` in your conditional statement

Answer (score 8):

Use the `argv` argument to `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);  //argv[0] will contain the name of the app.
    return 0;
}
```

You may need to scan the string to remove directory information and/or extensions, but the name will be there.

Comment: This solution has the added advantage of being cross-platform.

Comment: Yes it does, although I'm not looking for a cross platform one, just one for Windows using Win32 or .Net.

Comment: -1, in some case it doesn't work. For example, only type toolname(ignore .exe extension) in a command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Use __argv[0]

Comment: The simpliest and the best answer.

Comment: Only if the program started with `main` or `WinMain`, and not `wmain`, `wWinMain`. If "w" main is entry point, then `__wargv` has to be used. The other "argv" would remain null.

Answer (score 3):

There is a static Method on Assembly that will get it for you in .NET.

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName
```

Edit:  I didn't realize that you wanted the file name...  you can also get that by calling:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase
```

That will get you the full path to the assembly (including the file name).

Comment: While this seemed the way to go initially, it actually does not work in practice, as the assembly name is the same regardless of what the executable name gets set to.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it works under win64/visual studio 2017/ MFC

```
TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH + 1];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH + 1);
auto exe = CString(szFileName);
```

exe contains full path to exe.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> The global variable `_pgmptr` is automatically initialized to the full
>   path of the executable file, and can be used to retrieve the full path
>   name of an executable file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I like to make it a habit to add answers to really old questions. Let's do it again!

The very simplest way to get the current running .exe on a Windows system is to use the SDK defined global variable `_pgmptr`. However, it's considered "unsafe", so you use `_get_pgmptr()` instead.

So...

```
char *exe;
_get_pgmptr(&exe);
std::cout << "This executable is [" << exe << "]." << std::endl;
```

If you have a "wide" (UTF16) entrypoint, such as wmain or wWinMain, use this instead:

```
wchar_t* wexe;
_get_wpgmptr(&wexe);
std::wcout << L"This executable is [" << wexe << L"]." << std::endl;
```

If you really, really insist on using the simpler version, here's how to do it:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "This executable is [" << _pgmptr << "]." << std::endl;
}
```

Just don't get yourself pwned by hax0rs!