# Find what directory the running process EXE is stored in

Tags: c++, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the application executable name in Windows (C++ Win32 or C++/CLI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124886/how-to-get-the-application-executable-name-in-windows-c-win32-or-c-cli)

I can find what directory the process is running in using `GetCurrentDirectory()`, but what about finding the directory the executabke resides in?

Comment: This question is distinct from [How to get the application executable name in Windows (C++ Win32 or C++/CLI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/124886/145173) This question asks how to get the path to the directory. The other question asks how to get the path to the file.

Comment: It's not meaningfully different (note how the *accepted* answer to this references the same function as those in the linked dupe, just with less detail). Splitting the result into directory and filename after is trivial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx) or [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not clear to me where I get the HMODULE handle.

Comment: @John: `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`

Comment: If you want the main executable file, `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`. If you want a DLL, the handle to that DLL is (among other things) passed when `DllMain` is called.

Comment: OK, cool. So this gets me a pull path including the file-name. Is there a handy function to get me the full directory path, without the file-name? e.g takes c:\temp\app.exe and returns c:\temp?

Comment: @John: Yes, it's PathRemoveFileSpec -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks very much Jerry & Billy.

Answer (score -2):

In visual C++, we use

```
CString m_sAppFolder =  __targv[0] ;
```

which returns a string like "C:\blah\blah\executable_name.exe"

Comment: -1 for: 1. Unneeded dependence on MFC. 2. Having the same problem as Neil Moss's answer. 3. Using nonstandard `__targv`.

Comment: This technique should not be used. Callers of `CreateProcess` can make up whatever value they want for `argv[0]` - it doesn't even have to exist.