# Get list of files in application directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am developing a C++ application for win32 console

I need to get list of files in my application directory

(for example if my application had been started in `C:\arash\app\` I need list of files in this folder)

I searched and find `FindFirstFile` function in `windows.h` header , But this function need a directory path .

Can I use this function for getting list of files in my application running directory?

Thanks

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Default Funny, I can remember ["How do I write a good title?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/153990) to suggest the opposite.

Comment: @Kos interesting.. Although, I'd have to agree with Jeff Atwood on that "I think it is fine to duplicate the tags in the title, but only when they can be worked into the titles organically and conversationally." Here, it was not.

Comment: You are right , I am sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find what directory the running process EXE is stored in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364589/find-what-directory-the-running-process-exe-is-stored-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current working directory is '`.`'.

As noted in comments, this isn't necessarily the directory you want.

Comment: That is the Current Working Directory, which can change dynamically during the process's lifetime, and is not guaranteed to always reflect the folder that the app is running from.

Comment: `.` and `..` are relative to the process's CWD, not the actual .exe file. Things like OS file dialogs and desktop shortcuts can change the CWD, as well as code calling the `SetCurrentDirectory()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Use `GetModuleFileName()` with a NULL module handle to get the path and filename of the .exe file.  You can then strip off the filename portion, and use the remaining path as needed.