# How can a C program determine and print the location of its own executable?

Tags: c, file-io

I want to write a a C program that prints its location.

For example if i put the program exe file to `D:\myfolder\myc_prog`, it should print the same location `D:\myfolder\myc_prog` and if I put that exe file to the location `E:\mynewfold\` , it should print the updated location `E:\mynewfold`.

Actually, I have no idea how to do it that's why I'm not able to provide much details for this question.

Comment: Take a look at [How to get the current directory in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/298510/1890567)

Comment: will it help to use system("CMD_COMMANDS");  form #include<windows.h> to get current dir location ?

Comment: Your title refers to the current working directory, but what you describe in the question is the location of the executable. They're two different things. Which one do you want?

Comment: location of exe file. someone edit my title actually.

Comment: I fixed the title and updated the question a bit.

Comment: Keep in mind the solution may not be portable across platforms.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's not guaranteed to work. Depending on the system, if the program was executed via `$PATH` or equivalent, `argv[0]` is likely to be just the base name of the program (`"foo"` rather than `"/path/to/foo"`, for example).

Comment: @uchuugaka: Keep in mind the solution almost certainly *won't* be portable across platforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find what directory the running process EXE is stored in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364589/find-what-directory-the-running-process-exe-is-stored-in)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Windows, [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) should do the trick. Just pass `NULL` for the `hModule` parameter. Be sure to read the documentation carefully if you want to handle long file names (and you typically do). You'll also have to strip the name of the executable to get the directory path. A quick-and-dirty way to do so is to remove everything after the last `\`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buff[256];
    if(GetCurrentDirectory(256, buff)){//get current directory
        printf("%s\n", buff);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Similar to `getenv("PWD")` in linux?