# GetModuleFileName fill an adress and not the executable name

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get the **current executable application name** of my **windows console application**.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000877/how-can-i-get-the-current-instances-executable-file-name-from-native-win32-c), the solution should be to use [GetModuleFileNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function.

The problem is the **function doesn't fill the name** of the executable **but fill the address** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
    std::cout << "My executable name is : " << szFileName << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Output : `My executable name is : 0077F9DC`

Some one could fix my code ?

Comment: What is `TCHAR`? Is it `wchar_t` or `char`? In other words, are you compiling for Unicode or not? You also need to include error checking when you call winapi functions. You ignore the return value of `GetModuleFileName`. Don't do that.

Comment: your problem in `std::cout << szFileName`. `GetModuleFileName` work correct. but your display not correct. instead display content of `szFileName` you display address of  `szFileName`

Comment: Change `TCHAR` to `char` and `GetModuleFileName` to `GetModuleFileNameA`.  The code is mixing Unicode and non-Unicode in the output line and therefore just outputting the address of the buffer.

Comment: when TCHAR is defined as WCHAR you should use std::wcout (instead of std::cout) for output.

Comment: @RichardCritten No. Change `TCHAR` to `wchar_t` and use `std::wcout`.

Comment: @ric: The application location is outside the control of the application. Falling back to ANSI character encoding *will* fail at some point, when a user decides to place it into a directory, whose name cannot be represented in any one given ANSI codepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete code of the extraction current executable name :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH];
    // don't forget to check return values when calling winapi functions
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH); 
    std::wstring filePath(szFileName);
    std::size_t indexLastCharSlash = filePath.find_last_of(L"/\\");
    std::wstring fileName = filePath.substr(indexLastCharSlash + 1);
    std::wcout << fileName << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage use of ANSI text. Please don't encourage neglecting error checking on winapi calls.

Comment: I am not understand very well where is the problem. If you think is necessary, please edit my answer but it responds to the question. Is my code incompatible with UTF-8 ? I think we keep in mind that it print name of file so characters are limited.

Comment: The problem is that your code can't handle characters outside the prevailing ANSI codepage. You should use Unicode, which with winapi means `wchar_t` and then using `std::wcout` to output the value.

Comment: OK I understand, thank you for the feed back but some function like `find_last_of` and `substr` are not compatible with `wstring` so I don't know how to adapt it.

Comment: They are compatible with `wstring`

Comment: I edited my code. Thanks for your feed back. I will be careful with winapi functions which ends with `A` in the future.

Comment: I fixed a couple of minor issues

Comment: A helpful answer needs to at least identify the issue, and explain how the answer addresses it. *"Try this"* type of answers aren't useful.