# Reading the command a program was called from

Tags: c++, windows

If this has already been answered elsewhere, I'm sorry, I couldn't find it.

I have an interesting problem whereby I have a compiled program, `prog.exe`, which reads a file `prog.cfg` which contains the config. If I open `prog.exe` by double-clicking on it, everything's good. However, if I open it from a command line or batch file, I first have to set the directory. For example, if I have my program in a `progs` folder on the desktop, and from the desktop run `progs\prog.exe`, it doesn't load the config because it's looking for the config on the desktop ie in the current working directory.

This is fine if you know about it, but it's just another hoop for users to jump through. Is there a way in c++ to backtrack to the command used to launch the program to deduce whether the config file will be in the current working directory or not?

Alternatively, am I asking completely the wrong question?

Many thanks!

Comment: When you open it by double clicking on it the current directory is the one containing the executable. In a batch file the current directory need not be that folder. If this is your program you should be able to add logic to find the configuration file regardless of what the current folder is. If it is not you can make a batch file set the current directory before executing prog.exe.

Comment: The following should help (and likely some would consider this question to be a dupe of it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124886/how-to-get-the-application-executable-name-in-windowsc-cli

Comment: @drescherjm I know that's the issue, I was asking for help with fixing it, which I've just succeeded in doing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GetModuleFileName(nullptr, buf, bufsize)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a path to the executable.

Note that the standard `main` function's `argv[0]` is not guaranteed to provide that path, and when it provides a path, is not guaranteed to provide a programmatically usable representation of the path.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly, you always want your .exe read your .cfg file from the folder your .exe located? right?

try `argv[0]`.

`argv[0]` is your full .exe path when you run your exe, and it is a parameter of main function.

Comment: It usually *isn't* the full path.

Comment: In Windows, `main` arguments are ANSI-encoded, and so even when `argv[0]` contains a representation of the full path, it doesn't necessarily provide a faithful (programmatically usable) representation. Using `argv[0]` can work with a `wmain`, which is a common Windows extension. However, not all WIndows compilers support `wmain`.

Comment: As already pointed out, it isn't always the full path.  If you use the wide character version, however, it is usually a valid path relative to the current directory.  (But it doesn't have to be, so GetModuleFileName is a better choice.)