# How to open image in folder near executable in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I'm setting up a simple window in c++ Win32 which will show GIF animation as background. And the file is in directory of executable+gifs\test.gif.
And how to split executable name then append other path????
How can I do it?

I've tried with giving full path of gif and it worked, but it won't work on another computer.

```
#define DRAW_ANIM   1
static HWND hWnd;
static HDC hMWDC;
static Graphics* pGphcs = NULL;
static Image* pImg = NULL;
static unsigned int nFrm = 0, nFrmCnt = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {


    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE: 

        hMWDC = GetDC(hwnd);
            pGphcs = new Graphics(hMWDC);

            pImg = new Image(L"gifs\\test.gif");
            if (pImg) {
                nFrmCnt = pImg->GetFrameCount(&FrameDimensionTime);
                SetTimer(hwnd, DRAW_ANIM, 100, NULL);

            }

        break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        if (wParam == DRAW_ANIM)
        {
            pImg->SelectActiveFrame(&FrameDimensionTime, nFrm);
            Rect DRC(0, 0, pImg->GetWidth(), pImg->GetHeight());
            pGphcs->Clear(Color(128, 128, 128));
            pGphcs->DrawImage(pImg, DRC);
            if (nFrm < (nFrmCnt - 1)) nFrm++; else nFrm = 0;
        }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:

    delete pGphcs;
        delete pImg;
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hMWDC);
        KillTimer(hwnd, DRAW_ANIM);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect a gif showing, but nothing. ;(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the application executable name in WindowsC++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124886/how-to-get-the-application-executable-name-in-windowsc-cli)

Comment: No. My question is near to that, but I'm asked it for another result and for getting gif Executable Path.Split(EXECUTABLE NAME).append(other path)).

Comment: Then your question should be "how to split a path", which has already been answered many times on SO.

Comment: O yes. I didn't see that. I am not want to make duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not load files using relative paths. Use absolute paths instead. Use `GetModuleFileName()` to get the full path to your EXE, then strip off the filename portion and append the relative path for your GIF.

```cpp
#include <shlwapi.h>

WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
PathRemoveFileSpecW(path);
PathAppendW(path, L"gifs\\test.gif");
pImg = new Image(path);
```

Comment: Minor nitpick... be careful with `PathAppend` functions, there are newer and 'safer' ones in `<pathcch.h>`

Comment: @Mgetz I'm aware of the "safer" ones. But note that they are only available on Windows 8+. A lot of developers (myself included) still support older versions, at least Windows 7

Comment: But can you help in one problem?

Comment: There are a Rectangle in gray colour with size of minimized window. And I am showing window in SW_SHOWMAXIMAZED. And Textbox and button hidding behind gif. How can i solve it?

Comment: @TheGamerCoder those are different issues than the one asked in this question. You should post new questions for them.

Comment: OK. I did it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the timer cause a [WM_PAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) message (say, by calling [InvalidateRect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect)) and draw the current frame in response to that message.

Also, respond to [WM_ERASEBKGND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-erasebkgnd) and don't erase the background (return nonzero).

Comment: Emm... case WM_PAINT: